# PHP contact form - making a field not mandatory

Tags: php, contact-form

How can I make "email" field not mandatory? Even if someone is not filling the field, the form should submit.

In the below code, the "email" field is mandatory.

I tried to add if `!isset` email field so that the `$email_from` will get the word "empty", but it didn't work for me.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "aaaaa@aaaaa.com";

    $email_subject = "Messeage from your site";




    function died($error) {

    ?>


 <?php

        die();

    } 



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

        //!isset($_POST['email']) || /* i tried to comment this line, but didnt work. */

        !isset($_POST['telephone']))
{

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }


    $name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required


    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }





  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";






// create email headers

$headers = 'מאת: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'חזור ל: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
 <?php
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=thank_you.html">';    
    exit;   
    ?>



<?php



}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
 !isset($_POST['telephone'])){

 if(isset($_POST['email'])){
//all code for email inside here
}
}
```

this should do trick, while $_POST['email'] is empty it should´t bother you anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The `preg_match` on `$email_form` makes it required.

If you first check if `$email_form` is set, and than perform the `preg_match` it must work.

Like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
     if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
         $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br/>';
     }
} else {
     $email_from = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did , and it work:

```
    if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check if email is valid or not using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL in php5

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
    echo $email." E-mail is not valid.";
  }
  else
  {
    echo $email." E-mail is valid.";
  }
}
```